# Determine the values of a and b such that the following function is differentiable at 0

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Given this function below (sorry for bad formatting I tried my best but I am not really familiar with this)

f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 ax^3cos(1/x) +bx + b & \text{if}\, x< 0\\
 \sqrt{a+bx} &\text{if}\, x\geq 0\\
\end{cases}

Solve for a and b such that the following function is differentiable at 0. I used the property of continuous functions at x = 0 to create 2 simultaneous equations and manage to obtain a value where a = 1/4.

However as to the value of b, I've gotten mixed responses where some say b = 0, others say b = 1/2. Hope to get some clarification as to the value of b for this question!

Comment: By the condition of continuity, you have $b=\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is differentiable at $0$ then it is also continuous at $0$. But then

$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x) \iff \sqrt{a}=\lim_{x\to0} \big(ax^3\text{cos}(\frac{1}{x})+bx+b \big)\iff \sqrt{a}=b$$

Also

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ ax^3\text{cos}(\frac{1}{x})+bx+b-\sqrt{a}}{x-0} \iff \frac{1}{2}(a+b\times0)^{-\frac{1}{2}}b=\lim_{x\to0}\big(ax^2\text{cos}(\frac{1}{x})+b+\frac{b-\sqrt{a}}{x}\big)\iff \frac{1}{2}=0 +b+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{x}$$

So $b=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a=\frac{1}{4}$.

In fact if $b=0$ then $a=0$ but then $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable at $0$. The detail is when you calculate $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}(a+b\times x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}b$. The limit only exists if $a\neq0$ and $a>0$. If $a=0$ you obtain the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity you must have $\lim_{x \to 0^- } f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) $, then you can see that you obtain $b = \sqrt{a}$.

Now differentiating the two pieces and imposing $\lim_{x \to 0^- } f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x) $ you will obtain $b =\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}} $. So $a$ must be different from $0$.

Then $a = \frac{1}{4}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Despite that fact that your answer leads to the result, your solution is forcing the continuity of $f'$, which is a stronger result.

Comment: yes, it's stronger but the result is valid, anyway

Comment: thanks for the remark!